# How to either disable scrolling in md-content or have a min-height when on mobile

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-material

I'm using Angular Material's md-content directives to create a section that flexes to fill the usable vertical space and scrolls it's content. The problem is when viewing the page with a small screen, the content shrinks to the point that it effectively disappears. I'd like the md-content to stop scrolling or have a min-height so the page scrollbar shows up and the user can still see the content.

**Update:** Here's a plunker to demonstrate the problem: https://plnkr.co/edit/NVbEHo0CPxX5Zzi4U88U?p=preview

```
  <body layout="column">
  <div>
    <h1>Header</h1>
  </div>
  <md-content layout="row">
    <div flex="50">Left Column</div>  
    <md-content flex="50" layout="column">
      <h2>Section Header</h2>
      <md-content layout="column" flex>
        <h3>Scroll Header</h3>
        <md-content flex layout="column" style="min-height: 300px">
          <md-content flex>
            scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>
            scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>
            scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>
          </md-content>
        </md-content>
      </md-content>
    </md-content>
  </md-content>
</body>
```

If the browser window is large, the scrollable content scrolls as expected. When you shrink the browser, the `md-content` with the scrollable content shrinks down to nothing.

**Update 2:** I updated my plunker with a better example. To get the desired section scrollable and have it flex to the bottom of the viewport, I have all of its parent elements as `md-content` elements with a `layout` attribute. I can set a `min-height` on the scrollable element, but when the browser is shrunk now its parent `md-content` has a scroll bar. I could put another `min-height` on *that* `md-content`, but that would require me to know the height of its content (which could be dynamic).

Ideally, when shrinking the browser vertically, I'd like the scrollable content to only shrink to its min-height, and then change the behavior of all its parent `md-content` elements to not scroll so only the `body` scroll bar appears.

Comment: ...and you think we can help you without a [mcve]...

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu, I included an example of the problem.

Comment: On some devices the first two paragraphs will occupy all the screen. So you need to set a point where your whole page overflows. What is the maximum percentage of window height the first paragraphs may occupy?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu, I'd want them to occupy the whole screen if needed. I updated my question to hopefully give a better picture of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The example and the answer both have 2 javascript errors. Angular-material is not loaded, since `md-content` is a directive this could cause problems. Besides that, I don't exactly know how it works with angular2, there is also an angular2 error in the console.

I updated the example to angular-material-1.0.0/angular-1.4.8 and added a module and the `ngMaterial` dependency.

Now to your problem: usually a small screen height also comes with a small screen width, therefor you may be able to use the angular-material [layout breakpoints](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/introduction). In my example I use the `xs/gt-xs` breakpoint (599/600px width) to switch between the layouts by applying `layout-xs/layout-gt-xs` and `flex-gt-xs`. Small devices use a column layout and the outer `md-content` is the only thing that scrolls. Bigger devices use a row layout and the inner `md-content` scrolls.

```js
angular.module('app', ['ngMaterial']);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=RobotoDraft:300,400,500,700,400italic" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

<body ng-app="app" layout-gt-xs="column">
  <md-content flex layout="column">
    <div>
      <h1>Header</h1>
    </div>
    <md-content flex-gt-xs layout="row" layout-xs="column">
      <div flex-gt-xs="50">Shrink the browser vertically to see the problem with the scroll bars. The parent md-content scrolls instead of the body.</div>  
      <md-content flex-gt-xs="50" layout="column">
        <h2>Section Header</h2>
        <md-content flex-gt-xs layout="column">
          <h3>Scroll Header</h3>
          <md-content flex-gt-xs layout="column">
            <md-content flex-gt-xs>
              scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>
              scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>
              scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>scrollable content<br/>
            </md-content>
          </md-content>
        </md-content>
      </md-content>
    </md-content>
  </md-content>
</body>
</html>
```

You might be able to take a better look in the [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/4PdVZ1PyKI6L7DsgGs91), the layout stuff is hard to test in the included snippets.